# Swift problem in decrypt .net encrypted string

Tags: .net, swift, aes

I have a .net service which returns an ecrypted AES string
 using "CryptLib cross platform AES encryption decryption" found on GitHub for android and swift

link for CryptLib: https://github.com/skavinvarnan/Cross-Platform-AES

in android i managed to decrypt the string returned from the server successfully
but in IOS it keeps giving me errors or strange output data like :

ÄÄ¾IßþÑÔ×Q0•‹z•lz·'ù\u{0E} ¤*]9\u{15}ï!�EF\nëåtk/t\rÄ\u{07}K{-êg&ZÓ?\0o�¸\u{06}ˆ)ŸÝSX7ÜF\u{0F}]€[ïÎX-‰TÌœâ]¿ü.‚\nS\u{19}ÂN3!\u{15}\u{10}Ðš¥ÍQUö„›'Ï~N\u{0E}€‚F;»ª:sÿÒZ°óD:¿\u{19}\u{1A}†ŽvL

here is an example to try

IV = 509+QAilldg3dj3p

Key string used = 2c8bc04829771e56a064e192425f0f98

Encrypted text =
LbA/hK1DfsyqvwPKuyvKH90cFh6u6WfUBvFgv7XLtjNB4s++iJFSdLbAAIYLsFwh4HpZLzWMA5VCZTNwPUztvflIdTfyZ99y9B6Il+KHUKWNsgSlw6WgPw9ZGy+3zpZkaYmI8KkJj9hudeiCODxknXIJ26hkfjbAl9BRJg2GHyNKN1or+DR82Gxtfx6srbHS1jV/vItcZEOKRdaWzdRhGZ1HwYOD5cVg6xdt8Gts3dU=

java code

```
import android.util.Base64;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class CryptLib {

/**
 * Encryption mode enumeration
 */
private enum EncryptMode {
    ENCRYPT, DECRYPT
}

// cipher to be used for encryption and decryption
Cipher _cx;

// encryption key and initialization vector
byte[] _key, _iv;

public CryptLib() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    // initialize the cipher with transformation AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    _cx = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    _key = new byte[32]; //256 bit key space
    _iv = new byte[16]; //128 bit IV
}

/**
 * Note: This function is no longer used.
 * This function generates md5 hash of the input string
 *
 * @param inputString
 * @return md5 hash of the input string
 */
public static final String md5(final String inputString) {
    final String MD5 = "MD5";
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance(MD5);
        digest.update(inputString.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aMessageDigest : messageDigest) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDigest);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

/**
 * @param _inputText     Text to be encrypted or decrypted
 * @param _encryptionKey Encryption key to used for encryption / decryption
 * @param _mode          specify the mode encryption / decryption
 * @param _initVector    Initialization vector
 * @return encrypted or decrypted string based on the mode
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 * @throws InvalidKeyException
 * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
 * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
 * @throws BadPaddingException
 */
private String encryptDecrypt(String _inputText, String _encryptionKey,
                              EncryptMode _mode, String _initVector) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
        InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    String _out = "";// output string
    //_encryptionKey = md5(_encryptionKey);
    //System.out.println("key="+_encryptionKey);

    int len = _encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8").length; // length of the key provided

    if (_encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8").length > _key.length)
        len = _key.length;

    int ivlen = _initVector.getBytes("UTF-8").length;

    if (_initVector.getBytes("UTF-8").length > _iv.length)
        ivlen = _iv.length;

    System.arraycopy(_encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, _key, 0, len);
    System.arraycopy(_initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, _iv, 0, ivlen);
    //KeyGenerator _keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    //_keyGen.init(128);

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(_key, "AES"); // Create a new SecretKeySpec
    // for the
    // specified key
    // data and
    // algorithm
    // name.

    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(_iv); // Create a new
    // IvParameterSpec
    // instance with the
    // bytes from the
    // specified buffer
    // iv used as
    // initialization
    // vector.

    // encryption
    if (_mode.equals(EncryptMode.ENCRYPT)) {
        // Potentially insecure random numbers on Android 4.3 and older.
        // Read
        // https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html
        // for more info.
        _cx.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);// Initialize this cipher instance
        byte[] results = _cx.doFinal(_inputText.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Finish
        // multi-part
        // transformation
        // (encryption)
        _out = Base64.encodeToString(results, Base64.DEFAULT); // ciphertext
        // output
    }

    // decryption
    if (_mode.equals(EncryptMode.DECRYPT)) {
        _cx.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);// Initialize this ipher instance

        byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(_inputText.getBytes(),
                Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decryptedVal = _cx.doFinal(decodedValue); // Finish
        // multi-part
        // transformation
        // (decryption)
        _out = new String(decryptedVal);
    }
    //System.out.println(_out);
    return _out; // return encrypted/decrypted string
}

/***
 * This function computes the SHA256 hash of input string
 *
 * @param text   input text whose SHA256 hash has to be computed
 * @param length length of the text to be returned
 * @return returns SHA256 hash of input text
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 */
public static String SHA256(String text, int length) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String resultStr;
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] digest = md.digest();

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte b : digest) {
        result.append(String.format("%02x", b)); //convert to hex
    }
    //return result.toString();

    if (length > result.toString().length()) {
        resultStr = result.toString();
    }
    else {
        resultStr = result.toString().substring(0, length);
    }

    return resultStr;

}

/***
 * This function encrypts the plain text to cipher text using the key
 * provided. You'll have to use the same key for decryption
 *
 * @param _plainText Plain text to be encrypted
 * @param _key       Encryption Key. You'll have to use the same key for decryption
 * @param _iv        initialization Vector
 * @return returns encrypted (cipher) text
 * @throws InvalidKeyException
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
 * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
 * @throws BadPaddingException
 */

public String encrypt(String _plainText, String _key, String _iv)
        throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {
    return encryptDecrypt(_plainText, _key, EncryptMode.ENCRYPT, _iv);
}

/***
 * This funtion decrypts the encrypted text to plain text using the key
 * provided. You'll have to use the same key which you used during
 * encryprtion
 *
 * @param _encryptedText Encrypted/Cipher text to be decrypted
 * @param _key           Encryption key which you used during encryption
 * @param _iv            initialization Vector
 * @return encrypted value
 * @throws InvalidKeyException
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
 * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
 * @throws BadPaddingException
 */
public String decrypt(String _encryptedText, String _key, String _iv)
        throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {
    return encryptDecrypt(_encryptedText, _key, EncryptMode.DECRYPT, _iv);
}

/**
 * this function generates random string for given length
 *
 * @param length Desired length
 *               * @return
 */
public static String generateRandomIV(int length) {
    SecureRandom ranGen = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] aesKey = new byte[16];
    ranGen.nextBytes(aesKey);
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte b : aesKey) {
        result.append(String.format("%02x", b)); //convert to hex
    }
    if (length > result.toString().length()) {
        return result.toString();
    }
    else {
        return result.toString().substring(0, length);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How about you post the Swift code that does the decrypting?

Comment: Are you definitely base64-decoding the input first? That's something you could easily have forgotten to do...

Comment: In the iOS library, they use the kCCKeySizeAES256, but it appears your key is of size kCCKeySizeAES128. I'm not sure if that does matter during the decryption operation, but it might...

Comment: I have tried to perform a decrypt operation on the provided data, but I too get garbage data. I do believe that is also due to the fact that I'm not sure what kind of data I'm provided with. What encoding is used for the iv, key and encrypted text? The IV looks like default UTF8, the key looks like hex encoding (hence my comment about key size) and the encrypted text looks like base64. Can you confirm any of this?

Comment: @mag_zbc , the iPhone code is in the link provided

Comment: @Craz1k0ek , I tried to change the 
kCCKeySizeAES256 to kCCKeySizeAES128 but no luck

I use the IV and the key using the following functions 
IV = generateRandomIV()
Key = SHA256()

as I said, I managed to decrypt the same string in android, but in IOS I returns garbage

Comment: @ManMan I’m interested in the actual data type and representation of the provided data. Again, the iv looks odd, the key looks like hex and the ciphertext looks like base64. Make sure you have the same data loaded in memory for iOS ánd Android, i.e. Android uses bytes for encryption, meaning iOS should use the `Data` type for encryption, but make sure it’s initialized properly